Error Didn't find class on path: DexPathList with R8 & Proguard Rules
I have a problem launching our application. Since I launched the first version of the application there was no problem, I was going to launch the second version and I got an unexpected fatal error, the error of the classes with R8 and Proguard Rules. Can someone solve this for me?
proguard-rules.pro (app):
# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

-dontwarn java.awt.image.BufferedImage
-dontwarn javax.imageio.ImageIO
-dontwarn javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream

-dontwarn com.adgutech.commons.ConstantsKt
-dontwarn com.adgutech.commons.activities.ATHToolbarActivity
-dontwarn com.adgutech.commons.extensions.SharedPreferencesExtensionKt
-dontwarn com.adgutech.commons.extensions.ToastExtensionKt
-dontwarn com.adgutech.commons.helpers.MaterialValueHelper
-dontwarn com.adgutech.commons.helpers.TintHelper
-dontwarn com.adgutech.commons.helpers.ToolbarContentTintHelper
-dontwarn com.adgutech.commons.preferences.supportv7.ATEPreferenceFragmentCompat
-dontwarn com.adgutech.commons.themes.ThemeMode
-dontwarn com.adgutech.commons.themes.ThemeStore$Companion
-dontwarn com.adgutech.commons.themes.ThemeStore
-dontwarn com.adgutech.commons.utils.ATHUtil
-dontwarn com.adgutech.commons.utils.ColorUtil

build.gradle (app):
android {
    namespace = "com.adgutech.adomusic"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.build.compileSdk.get().toInt()

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.adgutech.adomusic"
        minSdk = libs.versions.build.minSdk.get().toInt()
        targetSdk = libs.versions.build.targetSdk.get().toInt()
        versionCode = libs.versions.app.versionCode.get().toInt()
        versionName = libs.versions.app.versionName.get()

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix = "-debug"
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        buildConfig = true
    }
    lint {
        checkReleaseBuilds = false
        abortOnError = true
        warning += mutableSetOf("ImpliedQuantity", "Instantiatable", "MissingQuantity", "MissingTranslation")
    }
    compileOptions {
        val javaVersion = JavaVersion.valueOf(libs.versions.build.javaVersion.get())
        sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
        targetCompatibility = javaVersion
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
    }
    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = project.libs.versions.build.kotlinJVMTarget.get()
    }
    dependenciesInfo {
        includeInApk = false
        includeInBundle = false
    }
}

App2:
package com.adgutech.adomusic

import android.app.Application
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager
import com.adgutech.adomusic.appshortcuts.DynamicShortcutManager
import com.adgutech.adomusic.helpers.WallpaperAccentManager
import com.adgutech.commons.isVersionOMR1
import com.adgutech.commons.themes.ThemeStore
import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidContext
import org.koin.core.context.startKoin

class App2 : Application() {

    private val wallpaperAccentManager = WallpaperAccentManager(this)

    companion object {
        private var instance: App2? = null

        fun getContext(): App2 {
            return instance!!
        }
        fun isProVersion(): Boolean {
            return BuildConfig.DEBUG
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        instance = this

        startKoin {
            androidContext(this@App2)
            modules(appModules)
        }

        // default theme
        if (!ThemeStore.isConfigured(this, 3)) {
            ThemeStore.editTheme(this)
                .accentColorRes(R.color.blue_dark_default)
                .coloredNavigationBar(true)
                .commit()
        }
        wallpaperAccentManager.init()

        if (isVersionOMR1) {
            DynamicShortcutManager(this).initDynamicShortcuts()
        }

        // Set Default values for now playing preferences
        // This will reduce startup time for now playing settings fragment as Preference listener of AbsSlidingMusicPanelActivity won't be called
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference_playback, false)
    }

    override fun onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate()
        wallpaperAccentManager.release()
    }
}

Logat:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.adgutech.adomusic, PID: 30520
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/adgutech/commons/themes/ThemeStore;
    at com.adgutech.adomusic.App2.onCreate(Unknown Source:15)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5781)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1690)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6548)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didnt find class "com.adgutech.commons.themes.ThemeStore" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.adgutech.adomusic-SvLW6RO-86qBCO-pAtr4uA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.adgutech.adomusic-SvLW6RO-86qBCO-pAtr4uA==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.adgutech.adomusic.App2.onCreate(Unknown Source:15) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5781) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1690) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6548) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)


Please add logcat to see what happens.

Looks as if you are missing some dependency. Did you add -dontwarn com.adgutech.commons.themes.ThemeStore because you got an error? If that is missing at compile time, then it will also be missing at runtime.
